# How to implement e and props in React TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have a **JS** Component in which I have defined some normal **jsx** functions and states and now I want to use them as props in a tsx file, but since I'm a beginner, I'm confused. this is the js version of what I want to implement in **tsx**:

```
export class FormUserDetails extends Component {
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };

  render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
    return (
    ...
            <AppBar title="Enter User Details" />
            <TextField
              placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
              label="First Name"
              onChange={handleChange('firstName')}
              defaultValue={values.firstName}
              margin="normal"
                            fullWidth="true"
            />
...
```

How to implement this in React TypeScript with:

```
export class MainInfo extends Component<Props,{}>
```

or similar?

Sandbox:it has my tsx file that I want to implement like my example in question and the JS file defining my props
https://codesandbox.io/s/tsx-rj694

Comment: could you paste the complete file?

Comment: @vjr12 https://codesandbox.io/s/tsx-rj694 I uploaded the tsx file I want to implement like my question and the main JS file that has my props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can make types for your class component this way

```
interface IProps {
 nextStep: () => void;
 values: {
    firstName: string
 };
 handleChange: (value: string) => void
}

export class FormUserDetails extends Component<IProps> {
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };

  render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
    return (
    ...
            <AppBar title="Enter User Details" />
            <TextField
              placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
              label="First Name"
              onChange={handleChange('firstName')}
              defaultValue={values.firstName}
              margin="normal"
                            fullWidth="true"
            />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide an interface for your component's props. For the case of `FormUserDetails`, you will need to define an interface or type alias that contains `values` and `handleChange`.

```
interface FormUserDetailsProps {
  values: {
    name: string; // include other required properties
  };
  handleChange: (value: string) => void;
}

export class FormUserDetails extends Component<FormUserDetailsProps> {
  // do the rest here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

but you can also use function component because it's much cleaner, nicer and more readable specially when using typescript:

```
interface IProps {
 nextStep: () => void;
 handleChange: (value: string) => void
 values: {
    firstName: string
 };
}

const FormUserDetails = (props: IProps) => {
  const { values, handleChange, nextStep } = props;
  const continue = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    nextStep();
  };

    return (
        <AppBar title="Enter User Details" />
        <TextField
            placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
            label="First Name"
            onChange={handleChange('firstName')}
            defaultValue={values.firstName}
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth="true"
        />
)}
```